# Java voice chat - all ends are having their own voice echoed back

Tags: java, audio, voice

I've written a p2p voice chat application in java using the sound.sampled api and I can carry out conversations with other people, but I'm actually hearing my voice echoed back to me and I'm only sending my voice packets to other connections (not myself). Other user says he can hear his voice echoed back to him as well.

This is a snippet of the audio capture and playback I'm using, which has a pretty bad echo as well.

```
package soundtest;

import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Soundtest extends JFrame{


public static void main(String[] args) {
    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(44100, 16, 2, true, true);

    DataLine.Info targetInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format); //Read from
    DataLine.Info sourceInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format); //Write to


    try{
        TargetDataLine microphone = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(targetInfo);
        microphone.open(format);
        microphone.start();

        SourceDataLine speakers = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(sourceInfo);
        speakers.open(format);
        speakers.start();

        int numBytesRead;
        byte[] targetData = new byte[microphone.getBufferSize() / 5];

        for(;;){
        numBytesRead = microphone.read(targetData, 0, targetData.length);

        if (numBytesRead == -1) break;
        speakers.write(targetData, 0, numBytesRead);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Does anyone know what the cause of the echoing could be?

Comment: Are you monitoring the mic in on your systems?

Comment: hmm, there seems to be a common echo cancellation problem out there.